# Converting from HTML to .NET MVC with Bootstrap

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am converting an web app from HTML with bootstrap to ASP.Net (C#) MVC with Bootstrap.  I've moved the index file into the View, I've added to theme (dashboard.css) to the Content directory, I've added my images to the images directory, and I've updated the bundle config file.

When I run the HTML page in Firefox, I get the correct layout with 12 items in a row.  When I run it with ASP.Net MVC, I only get 4 items in the row.  Everything is very big compared to straight HTML.  I am trying to get the 12 items in the row like HTML.  This is my first ASP.Net MVC app.  Any advice on where I should look next?  Here is my View file:

```
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="nav nav-justified">
                <li><a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/Logo-Smaller.png" alt="Jenkins"></a></li>
            </ul>   
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="jenkins.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="aboutus.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2 sidebar">
            <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Products <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#JFans">Jenkins Replacement Fans</a></li>
                <li><a href="#MFans">Manufacturer Fans</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Protection">Motor Protection</a></li>
                <li><a href="#MParts">Electric Motor Parts</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main col-lg-10">
            <span class="anchor" id="JFans"></span>                 
            <h3 class="page-header">Jenkins Replacement Fans</h3>
            <div class="row placeholders">
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-1 col-lrg-1 placeholder">
                    <img src="images/shrouded.JPG" class="img-responsive" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
                        <h4><a href="series1.html">shrouded</a></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-1 col-lg-1 placeholder">
                    <img src="images/shallow_recess.JPG" class="img-responsive" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
                    <h4>Shallow Recess</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-1 col-lg-1 placeholder">
                    <img src="images/paddle_wheel.JPG" class="img-responsive" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
                    <h4>Paddle Wheel</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-1 col-lg-1 placeholder">
                    <img src="images/flat_backed.JPG" class="img-responsive" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
                    <h4>Flat Backed</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-1 col-lg-1 placeholder">
                    <img src="images/flat_backed.JPG" class="img-responsive" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
                    <h4>Flat Backed</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-1 col-lg-1 placeholder">
                    <img src="images/flat_backed.JPG" class="img-responsive" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
                    <h4>Flat Backed</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-1 col-lg-1 placeholder">
                    <img src="images/shrouded.JPG" class="img-responsive" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
                    <h4>shrouded</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-1 col-lg-1 placeholder">
                    <img src="images/shallow_recess.JPG" class="img-responsive" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
                    <h4>Shallow Recess</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-1 col-lg-1 placeholder">
                    <img src="images/paddle_wheel.JPG" class="img-responsive" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
                    <h4>Paddle Wheel</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-1 col-lg-1 placeholder">
                    <img src="images/flat_backed.JPG" class="img-responsive" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
                    <h4>Flat Backed</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-1 col-lg-1 placeholder">
                    <img src="images/flat_backed.JPG" class="img-responsive" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
                    <h4>Flat Backed</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-1 col-lg-1 placeholder">
                    <img src="images/flat_backed.JPG" class="img-responsive" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
                    <h4>Flat Backed</h4>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </
```

Here is my CSS file:

```
/*
 * Base structure
 */

/* Move down content because we have a fixed navbar that is 50px tall */
body {
  padding-top: 65px;
}

.navbar-brand {
    max-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
.navbar-brand >img {
    max-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -o-object-fit: contain;
    object-fit: contain;
    width: auto;
    padding-top: 0px;
    float: none;
}

.navbar-nav li a {
    line-height: 65px;
    height: 65px;
    padding-top: 0;
}

/*
 * Global add-ons
 */

.sub-header {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

/*
 * Top navigation
 * Hide default border to remove 1px line.
 */
.navbar-fixed-top {
  border: 0;
  background-color: #F0F0F0;

}



/*
 * Sidebar
 */

/* Hide for mobile, show later */
.sidebar {
  display: none;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 55px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto; /* Scrollable contents if viewport is shorter than content. */
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-right: 1px solid #eee;
  }
}
.table td {
    text-align:left !important;
}
/* Sidebar navigation */
.nav-sidebar {
  margin-right: -21px; /* 20px padding + 1px border */
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: -20px;
}
.nav-sidebar > li > a {
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.nav-sidebar > .active > a,
.nav-sidebar > .active > a:hover,
.nav-sidebar > .active > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #428bca;
}


/*
 * Main content
 */

.main {
  padding: 20px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .main {
    padding-right: 40px;
    padding-left: 40px;
  }
}
.main .page-header {
  margin-top: 0;
}


/*
 * Placeholder dashboard ideas
 */

.placeholders {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
.placeholders h4 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.placeholder {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.placeholder img {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.anchor{
  display: block;
  height: 85px; /*same height as header*/
  margin-top: -85px; /*same height as header*/
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Open your browser console/network tab to see whether stylesheets are loaded properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference in HTML with bootstrap and MVC with Bootstrap so far you are using the same version of Bootstrap. I have converted many commercial HTML Bootstrap themes into MVC Bootstrap themes and it is pretty straight forward.

First of all you are missing a closing body tag. It could be an issue.

Secondly, do not use MVC Bundles at the moment. Copy all your existing HTML in views and make sure all scripts and CSS is referenced to right path. Write a simple action method that just return the view. Once you get the desired output, you are good to modify HTML with dynamic elements.

Thirdly, make sure there is no padding or margin applied to the div where you are using the following code.

```
col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3
```

In last, use developer tools available in your browser to find out the exact output of HTML page. You can always edit the HTML and get the real time results in many modern browsers.

Comment: I create a new MVC project without  MVC bundles.  I copies my index file into the MVC project.  The top headere section with straight MVC is 65px.  The top header section with MVC is 114 px.  There is no place that I set the top header section to 114px.  When I look at the css rules in firefox, they are exactly the same.  I getting very frustrated with ASP.Net.

Comment: Ok.  This is weird.  It works fine in Google Chrome.  The size is the same in straight HTML as ASP.Net.  However, the size is much larger in Firefox for the ASP.Net version compared to straight HTML.  Must be a setting in Visual Studio for Firefox.

Comment: I cleared the cache and cookies in Firefox.  It's working now.  I did learn about the Firefox developer tools.  Thanks.